# Drop Down Menu Goes Away To Quick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I go to a sub menu on my Parent Link when I try and go to the grand child link the menu goes away to quick and does not allow me some times to click on the grand child link.

How can I make it so that can stay open until I click on a sub menu link or grand child link.

Codepen Example Here: http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/PwaemX

```
a.menu-link {
float: right;
display: block;
padding: 1em;
}

.menu, .menu > ul ul {
clear: both;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.js .menu, .js .menu > ul ul {
overflow: hidden;
max-height: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.menu.active, .js .menu > ul ul.active {
max-height: 55em;
}

.menu > ul {
border-top: 1px solid #808080;
}

.menu li a {
color: #000;
display: block;
padding: 0.8em;
border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
position: relative;
}

.menu li.has-subnav > a:after {
content: '+';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
display: block;
font-size: 1.5em;
padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
}

.menu li.has-subnav > a.active:after {
content: "-";
}

/* Start Mobile */

@media screen and (min-width: 48.25em) {
.pattern {
overflow: visible;
}

a.menu-link {
display: none;
}

.js .menu, .js .menu > ul ul {
max-height: none;
overflow: visible;
background: none;
}

.js .menu > ul ul {
background: #808080;
display: none;
}

.js .menu > ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}

.menu ul {
margin: 0 0 0 -0.25em;
border: 0;
}

.menu li a {
border: 0;
}

.menu li.has-subnav > a {
padding-right: 2em;
}

.menu li.has-subnav > a:after {
content: ">";
font-size: 1em;
padding: 0.8em 0.5em;
}

.menu .level-1 > li.has-subnav > a:after {
content: "▼";
}

.menu > ul li {
margin: 0 0.25em;
}

.menu > ul > li {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}

.menu > ul ul {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 12em;
width: 12em;
}

.menu > ul ul li {
position: relative;
}
.menu > ul ul.level-2 {
top: 3em;
left: 0;
}

} 

/* End Mobile */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This style causes the problem, because it creates a gap between the levels:

```
.menu > ul li {
  margin: 0 0.25em;
}
```

Change it to this:

```
.menu > ul li {
  padding: 0 0.25em;
}
```

**[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myKLpz)**

Answer (score 0):

you used `left:12em`to `.menu > ul ul`. For this, third ul is going so far. Use maximum `11.5em` to  `.menu > ul ul` below the example is ...

```
.menu > ul ul{
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 11.5em;
     width: 12em;
}
```